# API to use from magento store to iOS Application

Tags: ios, api, magento

I want to fetch data from Magento store to iOS application and I want to show all the products and all details like magneto store in my iOS application.

I very new to Magento about how to use it for iOS application. Can any one please suggest or guide me how can i use it for my iOS application.

I checked and what I found one link as [Magento API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html), As per this link we just have to replace domain and will it work?

Comment: @VarunNaharia sure..I am checking. I have one question can you please guide.. What I understand is "http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html" in this API I have to just replace my domain name and I can fetch products like  from product API http://magentohost/api/rest/products?

Comment: Yes you have just pass the link to your rest api

Comment: Yes, I downloaded but I am checking for the key from where  I can get "MAGENTO_API_KEY",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the [Magento API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) and there is one more unofficial client library for Magento Service that you can use is [LogNMagento](https://github.com/lognllc/LogNMagento)

Comment: Hey buddy can you guide me here for one thing? To use magento API, Do I need to implement oauth login in my iOS application?

Comment: This is with soap, I was trying with rest